# DEBUG/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol on Android

Tags: java, android, network-programming, android-networking

I create code like this:

```
try {
    int ct_id;
    String ct_name;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/update.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //paring data
    int max = 0;
    try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ct_id=json_data.getInt("max(id)");
            ct_name=json_data.getString("date");
            max = ct_id;
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){

} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

but when I debug it appeared:

```
07-03 08:50:42.657: DEBUG/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

what is that mean? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a local url , are you sure your apache is running on port 80? can you try accessing this url http://10.0.2.2/update.php in desktop browser and do u see things properly. This error generally comes only if socket is not able to establish connection with server.